# How to force trailing zeroes in 'polynom::polynomial' object? (specifically to modify behavior of stat_lm and stat_regline_equation from ggpubr)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr, ggpmisc

I am trying to modify how `stat_regline_equation` displays the regression line equation on a plot made with `ggscatter` from the R package `ggpubr`. Specifically, I want to show a consistent number of digits of coefficients, even when some rounded coefficients have trailing zeros, which are typically removed. Here is an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

diamonds %>%
  filter(color %in% c("E", "H", "I")) %>%
  ggscatter(x="carat", y="table", add="reg.line") +
    facet_wrap(~color) +
    stat_regline_equation(label.y.npc = 'top')
```

[image]

Graph I is fine, graph H has one trailing zero removed, and graph E has the slope removed entirely because it rounds to 1.00.
Based on a great answer I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66177005/im-using-stat-regline-equation-with-ggscatter-is-there-a-way-to-specify-the-si) as well as a different answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458729/keeping-trailing-zeros), I tried to modify the package code using `trace(ggpubr:::.stat_lm, edit = TRUE)` to modify lines 13 and 14 from

`eq.char <- as.character(signif(polynom::as.polynomial(coefs), 2))`

to

`eq.char <- as.character(formatC(polynom::as.polynomial(coefs), format = "f", digits = 2))`

Here is the problem: if you pass a `polynom::polynomial` object to `signif` or `round`, they return another `polynom::polynomial` object, but for `formatC` or `sprintf` they return characters:

```
coefs = diamonds %>%
  filter(color=='E') %>%
  stats::lm(table~carat, .) %>%
  stats::coef()

coefs %>%
  polynom::as.polynomial() %>%
  formatC(format='f', digits=2) %>%
  class() %>%
  print()

coefs %>%
  polynom::as.polynomial() %>%
  signif(digits = 2) %>%
  class() %>%
  print()

[1] "character"
[1] "polynomial"
```

Therefore my attempt to use `formatC` above doesn't work. I am guessing that the `polynom::polynomial` class has built-in methods for `round` and `signif`, and none for `formatC`, so the output is coerced for the latter. I could potentially try to modify the class definition of `polynom::polynomial`, but at this stage I feel like there has to be an easier way to get trailing zeros on the regression equations that display on my graphs. And I am hoping that this is a common enough desire that someone has an easier solution, or at the very least that an answer might be useful to more people besides myself.

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT: This answer only partly fixes the problem. It still displays only `56.83 + 1 x` instead of `1.00 x`. I'm leaving the answer since someone else may be able to build from this.***

A big part of the problem is `polynom:::print.polynomial`, which contains:

```r
p <- as.character.polynomial(signif(x, digits = digits), decreasing = decreasing)
```

This will never print trailing zeroes due to `as.character.polynomial`. So, we can just create a new `as.character.polynomial` that DOES allow that. I just modified the existing code a bit as an example, and you can tweak it further:

```r
as.character.polynomial <- function (x, decreasing = FALSE, digits = 2, nsmall = 2) {
  p <- format(unclass(x), digits = digits, nsmall = nsmall)
  lp <- length(p) - 1
  names(p) <- 0:lp
  p <- p[as.numeric(p) != 0]
  if (length(p) == 0) 
    return("0")
  if (decreasing) 
    p <- rev(p)
  signs <- ifelse(as.numeric(p) < 0, "- ", "+")
  signs[1] <- if (signs[1] == "- ") "-" else ""
  np <- names(p)
  pow <- paste("x^", np, sep = "")
  pow[np == "0"] <- ""
  pow[np == "1"] <- "x"
  stars <- rep.int("*", length(p))
  stars[p == "" | pow == ""] <- ""
  paste0(signs, p, stars, pow, collapse = " ")
}
```

Example:

```r
coefs %>%
  polynom::as.polynomial() %>%
  as.character.polynomial
# [1] "56.83 + 1.00*x
```

However, `.stat_lm` will then output it as `` italic(y)~`=`~56.83 + 1.00*~italic(x) ``, and it will consequently be used as an expression. I'm not familiar enough with `ggplot2` to figure out the rest, so I'll leave that to someone else.

[image]

Comment: This will not necessarily work if the character string is converted into an R expression, because `expression()` itself drops trailing zeros.
`expression(56.83 + 1.00*x)` returns `expression(56.83 + 1 * x)`.

Comment: @PedroAphalo Yep, you're right. When actually implementing it in the whole call it only gets to "1 * x". I'll leave the answer so someone else can build upon it, and I added a message at the top.

Comment: This is a great start, and I really appreciate you taking the time @slamballais. Expression parsing has always confounded me. I guess now is my chance to figure it out.

Comment: @slamballais Are you o.k. if I edit 'ggpmisc' to define and use an edited version of your `as.character.polynomial()` function? I can add you as contributor is you send me your name (privately) as you would like it mentioned in DESCRIPTION.

Comment: Hey @PedroAphalo, feel free to just use it without my name :)

Comment: Many thanks @slamballais! I ended using `sprintf()` rather than `format()`, with a call:
`sprintf("%.*#g", digits, x)`

Answer (score 3):

As one problem is `expression()` we get closer to the desired output using package 'ggtext' and the equations formatted as markdown. Package 'ggpmisc' follows the grammar of graphics so there is more to type than with 'ggpubr' but it retains all the flexibility of 'ggplot2' and the concept of layers. It formats equations as R expressions by default but it also can return LaTeX and markdown formatted equations. It uses `signif()` internally so the number of digits after the decimal point can vary. The number of significant digits can be controlled through parameter `coef.digits`.

The values retain trailing zeros based on the number of significant digits rather than the number of digits after the decimal point as small coefficients for high order terms of a polynomial are important.

I prefer `theme_bw()` to `theme_classic()` for plots with panels, `theme_classic()` would give a plot formatted almost as in the question.

[code updated for R (>= 4.2.0) and 'ggpmisc' (>= 0.4.5).]

```r
library(ggpmisc)
#> Loading required package: ggpp
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggpp'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     annotate
library(ggtext)

diamonds |>
  subset(color %in% c("E", "H", "I")) |>
  ggplot(aes(x=carat, y=table)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_poly_line() +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = after_stat(eq.label)),
               geom = "rich_text", output.type = "markdown",
               label.y = 72, label.x = 1, fill = NA, label.size = NA,
               hjust = 0) +
  facet_wrap(~color) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Note:** The statistic `stat_poly_eq()` in package 'ggpmisc' is the original piece of code which was copied without acknowledgement and renamed as `stat_regline_equation()` in 'ggpubr'. Meanwhile, development of package 'ggpmisc' has continued and currently `stat_poly_eq()` has several new features and bug fixes. One of the features added soon after package 'ggtext' made it to CRAN is the support for markdown encoded equations, which I used in the example above.

Comment: This is really interesting, thank you for taking the time. This looks something I could work with. However, I'm having issues reproducing the example above. I'm getting the error `Error in stat_poly_line() : could not find function "stat_poly_line"`. Really sorry if this is a mistake on my part. I will try to work it out one way or another.

Comment: looking at examples of the use of 'ggpmisc', I was able to successfully substitute `geom_smooth()` for `stat_poly_line()`. Unfortunately I can't get the slope for Graph H to display as '0.80', no matter what I set `coef.digits` to. The frustrating part is that graph E has correct trailing zeros, as yours does above. Again, I will continue to work on it, but any hints or thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: It will take me a few days before I have time to look into this, but it is in my to do list for 'ggpmisc'. The question is that in many cases what matters is the number of significant digits, not places behind the decimal point. The 1.00 x works because the code that I wrote in 'ggpmisc' treats it as a special case. I think the formatting should be so that the number of places after the leftmost significant digit remains the same in all cases.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking any time at all on this. People like me owe a big debt of gratitude to people like you who are willing to volunteer your time to develop packages. 
I find myself wondering how big a deal this is when a figure is reviewed for publication. As a grad student I can only guess, and try to cover my bases.

Comment: @Carl I am myself a user of 'ggpmisc' so I see correcting bugs and adding enhancements like time well invested. Questions like yours help improve a package, in this case for a feature that I expect to use myself frequently. The answer from @slamballais put me in a good rack to solving this issue for output other than `expression`. The best way to thank is to cite the package in your manuscript, if the journal allows it.  I see answering questions and publicly releasing my packages also as a way of paying back for the help I have received online over many years.

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying! I will cite if at all possible.